# Sending multiple responses from a Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services

I want to create a Web Service that receives images in the form of byte[] and Saves them in the FileSystem.

I want to keep sending the response as I'm saving the files on the FileSystem so that user can show the progress on the mobile device.

Currently I have built a Web Service that can receive only single image.

Here's my code to save single image-

```
[WebMethod]
public string upload(byte[] postedFile, string folderName, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        string to_post_in = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/"), folderName);

        File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(to_post_in, fileName), postedFile);

        SortedList slResult = new SortedList();
        slResult.Add("0", "Success");

        return  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(slResult);
    }
    catch
    {
        SortedList slResult = new SortedList();
        slResult.Add("1", "Error");

        return  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(slResult);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be possible!

As best I know, once you send a response back, code does not continue any further from that line.

You may do the following-

1. Use same code.
2. Send one by one pic from the iOS device.

That way you'll be able to tell what file was stored successfully and what not.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in one single function in Web Services

Why not trying to create the following?

Function `upload` to save the list of files like this

```
public string upload(List<byte[]> postedFile, string folderName, List<string> fileNameList)
{
    //code to save here
}
```

Function `checkUploaded` that takes a list of images name as parameter and checks how many images have already been saved-

```
public string checkUploaded(string folderName, List<string> fileNameList)
{
    //add code to check how many images of the list have already been saved
    //and return a percent       
}
```